# Setting VerticalContentAlignment in my WPF TabItem changes both the text in the tab and the Control contained in the tab

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, vertical-alignment

```xaml
<TabItem Header="Data Entry"
         FontSize="40"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         Height="75"
         Width="300"
         Background="#464646"
         Foreground="White"
         DataContext="{Binding Tabs[0]}">

    <Controls:DataEntryUserControl />

</TabItem>
```

My TabItem is formed with the code above. I want the text in the tab ("Data Entry") to be aligned to the center of the tab, but I want the UserControl to be aligned to the top of the window. However, both of these alignments change when I set `VerticalContentAlignment` (e.g. in the code above, both of them are aligned to the top of their respective parents). The `VerticalAlignment` property doesn't change anything.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I didn't try it yet, but I will as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `HeaderTemplate` where you specify the alignment of the header:

```xaml
<TabItem Header="Data Entry"
             FontSize="40"
             Height="75"
             Width="300"
             Background="#464646"
             Foreground="White"
             DataContext="{Binding Tabs[0]}">
    <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>

    <Controls:DataEntryUserControl />

</TabItem>
```